# How to instruct reftex to automatically pick the .bib file in local directory?

Tags: reftex-mode

Whenever I press `C-c [` in the main.tex file I get the message `No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available`. How do I set the default? Using helm-bibtex seems way to easy, using the option `helm-bibtex-with-local-biliography`. Is there anything equivalent int reftex?

MWE:

file --> main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
This is a test paragraph C-c [
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}
\end{document}
```

file --> publications.bib

```
@article{testkey,
author={J. Doe and I. Dane},
title={Fake title},
journal={Proc. of Int. Fake Journals},
year={2009},
}
```

Comment: Your example works out of the box for me with RefTeX (Emacs 27).  Can you start emacs with `-Q`, eval `(require 'reftex)` in scratch buffer and try it again?

Comment: It seems that reftex-mode was not properly started in latex-mode, something in my config might have messed things up.